# Getting Revisions ONLY in my directory and not in root Repository

Tags: php, svn, command-line, tortoisesvn

Ok, this is a little difficult to explain so bear with me.

Let's say for example I have this repository I'm working out of
*path/to/repos/users*

In this repository there is a bunch of different users for example.

*../../../users/me

../../../users/you*

And we're both making commits in TortoiseSVN like usual and for this example let's say revision 10 is the head revision. In the "../me" directory I've only submitted 10, 6, and 5. And the "../you" directory committed everything else.

If I were to use a svn command in that directory = `svn update -r PREV` and I were to check the version number using `svnversion` the number I would get is 9. However, I don't want 9. **Which brings me to my question, is there any way using the command line to update to previous revisions and get revisions that only "../me" submitted?**

Sorry if it is a little hard to understand, if there's anything I can provide to make it a bit clearer just let me know. Thank you.

Comment: It's really hard to follow what you're attempting to do here. Are you saying that you've checked out the whole repository, but only want to update  the `me` directory? Or do you want to update only items committed by a specific user?

Comment: @alroc Sorry, it was kind of difficult to explain. And Yes I've checked out that repository and I only wanted revisions from "me" directory, but I just figured out how to solve my problem. See my answer below.

Comment: Within a working copy, you can update any individual directory independently. If this is a regular occurrence, you probably shouldn't be checking out the whole repository in the first place - only check out what you need.

Comment: I understand your point, but it kind of drifted from my point because even if I had my directory, using svnversion to store the revision number in a variable for example, would give me the the number of the repository number (Say HEAD = 500). For the first call to svnversion, I will get 500 even though, my lastest working copy in my directory is 498. And if my commit before that was 490. If I did an svn update -r PREV, the next time I ran svnversion, I would not get 490 like I WANT to, I would get 499 because although it applies to the directory, it applies to the repository as well. @alroc

Comment: Nevertheless, thank you for your comments. Cheers. :) @alroc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue this morning, to answer my own question, when working with subfolders out of a checked out repository, every time a `svn update -r PREV` command is called, it updates to the previous revisions in *me* directory. However, running svnversion on at that point will give you the previous revision in `../../repos/users` to solve this issue, I called  `svn info .` in the `me` directory and noted that the **Last Changed Rev:** had the number that I needed. To get this I called svn info (this is in php btw):

`exec('svn info .', $info);`

Then I used a regular expression to grab the key:

`$versionKey = array_keys(preg_grep('/Last Changed Rev/', $info));`

And then set the version to that revision number using substr with an offset of 18:

`$version = substr($info[$versionKey[0]], 18);`